# Why does this loop have "2 for i in range"? What does it do?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the best way to find all factors of a number. I found this code, but I don't understand it:

```
import math

def get_factors(n):
    return sum(2 for i in range(1, round(math.sqrt(n)+1)) if not n % i)
```

What does this `2 for i in range` accomplish? How does this code work to compute the number of factors?

Comment: Did you try doing what you're asking?

Comment: Then you will calculate `sum` over iterator containing 1 or 3. What is the point of asking this question? rather than sum try printing the contents of the generator by converting it into a list. You will understand better than anyone answering this question here

Comment: Yes. I just can't understand the syntax in the return part. '2 for i ... '. What is 2 for?

Comment: That is more of a mathematical question. The answer is that because you go over all the factors until the square root - every factor has its pair, which is bigger than the square root. that's why you want to count each factor twice. (although I'm pretty sure this function won't work for numbers with actual root, because then it counts as only one factor)

Answer (score 4):

The generator expression is finding factors two at a time, so each time it finds a pair of factors it needs to add two to the count.

Here's the same loop in a clearer syntax:

```
def get_factors(n):
    total_factors = 0
    limit = round(math.sqrt(n) + 1)
    for i in range(1, limit):
        if n % i == 0:
            total_factors += 2
    return total_factors
```

---

How does this work as a generator expression? Let's unpack the syntax. The general form of a generator expression is:

*`result-expression`* `for` *`variable`* `in` *`iterable-expression`* `if` *`predicate`*

This will return a generator which will be an iterable object that contains the *`result-expression`* (which can be based on the *`variable`*, but isn't in this case) for each value in the given *`iterable-expression`* for which the *`predicate`* is true.

In this case, the *`result-expression`* is a constant `2`, so we get a `2` for every time in the loop that the *`predicate`* is true (that is, that `not n % i` is `True` in a boolean context, which means that `i` divides `n` evenly).

This entire generator expression is passed to `sum`, which takes an iterable argument and reduces it to a single value using the `+` operator; in this case, it takes all the `2`s and adds them together to give you a total.

---

OK, so *why* does this work? That's a mathematical question, not a programming one.

slallum mentioned this in the comment above, but to understand how this works, think about what it means for a number to have factors.

Let's pick a number like 12. 12 has six factors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12:

```
12 /  1  = 12
12 /  2  =  6
12 /  3  =  4
12 /  4  =  3
12 /  6  =  2
12 / 12  =  1
```

There's a clear symmetry here: each factor is paired with another factor:

```
        /-- square root of 12 = approx. 3.46
        |
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
 |  |  \--/     |                   |
 |  \-----------/                   |
 \----------------------------------/
```

Where is the dividing line where the two series of factors "cross over" each other? It's the square root. The square root of 12 is approximately 3.46, and indeed that's the line of symmetry around which the factors group. That's logical because of what a square root means: it's the number which, as a factor, would only be counted once.

The optimization is that you only need to count half the factors (those below the square root), and you know that there are corresponding factors above the square root. So each time you find a factor smaller than the square root, you count two factors.

As slallum points out in the comment, that's a sign that this implementation is wrong: it returns a count that is off by one for any number that is a perfect square. For example, 16 has 5 factors: 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16, but this implementation will say it has 6, because it's counting 4 twice.